# Слитно или раздельно: "Тут нет не()нужных программ"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Известный блогер написал такую вот фразу:

"Тут нет кучи часто совершенно не нужных программ."

Его поправили: мол, "ненужных" в данном случае надо писать слитно, так как нет противопоставления или акцентирования. И, вроде бы, это так.

Но! Возник вопрос: в чем разница между "не нужных" и "ненужных"? Мне кажется, что "не нужных" можно понимать как бесполезных в данный момент времени. А "ненужных" можно понимать как бесполезных вообще (хлам, например).Так ли это? И будет ли разным написание слов "ненужных/не нужных" в зависимости от контекста приведенного выше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Розенталя по этому поводу есть четкое правило: при утверждении (когда слово можно заменить синонимом без НЕ) частица НЕ пишется слитно: совершенно ненужных, т.е бесполезных программ. При отрицании частица НЕ пишется отдельно (совершенно не нужных программ, т.е. если мы отрицаем, что программы нужны, но при этом не утверждаем, что они бесполезны, иными словами, "серединка на половинку)

Comment: Пример  с  отрицанием  приведите,  пожалуйста.

Comment: Пример приведен в ответе. У Розенталя примеры такие: эта задача
 нетрудная (утверждается легкость), эта задача не трудная (отрицается трудность) и др. примеры См. Розенталя

Comment: Однако у Розенталя есть примечание:Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает наречие меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти), то НЕ с прилагательным пишется слитно. У нас как раз наречие меры: совершенно = очень

Answer (score 6):

***Тут нет кучи часто совершенно ненужных программ.*** – слитно, потому что можно заменить синонимом без НЕ- (лишних, бесполезных) и есть пояснительное слово – наречие меры и степени СОВЕРШЕННО. Каким бы Вы синонимом ни заменили – бесполезных, лишних, опасных, вредных и т. д. – будет писаться слитно, если это в принципе можно сделать. Раздельно будет только при наличии противопоставления и акцента на НЕ: *никому не нужный, ничуть не нужный, не нужный ли это человек?*

Answer (score 1):

Знаете, с этим правилом действительно есть сложность. Различия могут быть плохо выражены, бывает, что и двоякое написание возможно. Но в Вашем случае можно для простоты считать, что "бесполезные" (в любом понимании) влечет слитное написание "ненужных", а "не те,  которые нужны"(вредные, опасные - и проч) - раздельное. Но последнее маловероятно по смыслу. Более того, по моим наблюдениям наличие отрицания в сказуемом (у нас - "нет кучи") вообще исключает противопоставление, т.е. раздельное написание. Кроме, разве, очевидных
случаев явного отрицания ("Там нет ненужных программ, там вообще никаких нет").

Comment: Мне кажется,всё дело в слове "совершенно".Оно является определяющим.

"Тут нет кучи часто совершенно не (очень) нужных программ."
и
"Тут нет кучи часто  не(очень) нужных программ."

Второй вариант-совсем другое дело.

Comment: Я  бы  в  вашем  примере  слитно  написал.  Или: там  нет  ни  нужных,  ни  ненужных,  там  вообще  никаких  нет.